# Does the self keyword have any special meaning for a C struct?

Tags: objective-c, c

Trying to make sense of MTAudioProcessingTap sample code from WWDC 2012.

This structure is used by the Tap to pass data around.

```
typedef struct AVAudioTapProcessorContext {
    ...
    void *self; //Note use of word self
} AVAudioTapProcessorContext;
```

The word `self` here is used apparently as a standard variable name even though Xcode highlights it in pink. Is this just a code parsing oversight in Xcode?

Later, the Tap management class passes a reference to itself to this variable.

```
//Setting up Tap callbacks:
callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)self,

//And then storing it in the above struct when it's passed by the callback:
static void tap_InitCallback(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void **tapStorageOut)
{
    AVAudioTapProcessorContext *context = calloc(1, sizeof(AVAudioTapProcessorContext));

    ...
    context->self = clientInfo;

    *tapStorageOut = context;
}
```

And the confusion starts again in a later function (another Tap callback). Once again, the word self is used to refer to the Tap management class reference. Note that this occurs in a function defined after `@end` of the Tap management class implementation.

```
AudioFFTTapProcessor *self = ((__bridge AudioFFTTapProcessor *)context->self);
```

Comment: My best guess here is that the word `self` has no special significance as a variable name used outside a class implementation, so they are using it to refer to the class that these functions are closely associated with, and it just gets highlighted pink because Xcode doesn't check the context of the word `self`.

Comment: Not in C, http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Reserved-words-in-C.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` has a special meaning *only* in the context of an Objective-C method.  In all other contexts, it's just an ordinary identifier.  You can think of Objective-C methods as being rewritten to take a hidden parameter with the name `self` (and a second hidden parameter named `_cmd` that's not relevant for this discussion), e.g.:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)doSomething:(int)param1 withThis:(NSString *)param2
{
    // 'self' refers to the MyClass instance in this function
    ...
}
@end
```

could be imagined as if it were rewritten like this:

```
void MyClass_doSomething(id self, SEL _cmd, int param1, NSString *param2)
{
    // 'self' refers to the MyClass instance in this function
    ...
}
```

Outside of Objective-C methods, you can use `self` as any other kind of identifier, whether it be a local variable, a `struct` member, a global function, or type name, etc., though the latter uses should be highly discouraged due to high potential for confusion.

So yes, XCode highlighting the `self` instance in pink in the `struct` definition is just a parsing anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is not a keyword in C.  It's a keyword for Objective-C, which is probably why it's getting highlighted.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword, it just s special parameter name. just Xcode always highlight it no matter of what context

Answer (score 0):

`self` does not mean anything special as a C struct field name. Objective-C uses it as the equivalent of most other OO languages' `this`, which is why Xcode highlights it specially.